# Automatically move inline JavaScript to external file

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, inline

I'm developing a `Chrome App` and I'd like to reuse code built for another platform. Since this code is actually a bunch of HTML and some `JavaScript` here and there, theoretically it would be possible to turn it in a `Chrome App` without (almost) any changes. The only problem I'm facing is due to in-line `JavaScript`, which in `Chrome Apps` is not allowed for security reasons.

Since I don't have full control over the generated `HTML`, I need a way to automatically find in-line `JavaScript`, move it into external files and replace it with correct references to these files.

I haven't found any tool suitable for this task. Do you know one?

Maybe something already integrated with `Grunt.js` or similar stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a grunt task that parses the html code. You could use the [grunt-dom-munger](https://github.com/cgross/grunt-dom-munger) and define custom rules to extract the inline JavaScript.
Use the `dest` param to indicate where the code will be extracted.